# QTreeview iterate through list

Tags: qt

I need to iterate through the QTreeview list with buttons the way it natively does via the keyboard arrow keys. I can get it to jump to the last item with this code, but it won't iterate through the list, it just jumps to the last item.

```
for( int i = 0; i < ui->TList_Tree->topLevelItemCount(); ++i )
     {
        ui->TList_Tree->setCurrentIndex(ui->TList_Tree->currentIndex().sibling(i,0));
     }
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: If you can inherit from `QTreeView` then you could make use of [`QTreeView::moveCursor`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#moveCursor).

Comment: great idea, here's what I have so far, but it tells me moveDown is prtoected. I can't find any good examples on how to actually use moveCursor.

ui->TList_Tree->moveCursor(QAbstractItemView::MoveDown, Qt::NoModifier);

Comment: I've also tried:

QModelIndex ui->TList_Tree->moveCursor(QAbstractItemView::MoveDown, Qt::NoModifier);

but the error says it expects an initialzer before the -> token following ui.

Comment: `QTreeView::moveCursor` *is* protected.  That's why I asked if you could inherit from `QTreeView` -- you'll need to in order to make use of it.

Comment: sorry, still learning. Not sure how to inherit from QTreeView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comments above missed the rather obvious [`QTreeView::indexAbove`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#indexAbove) and [`QTreeView::indexBelow`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#indexBelow).  So your button that that moves the cursor down should connect to code that does something along the lines of...

```
QModelIndex index = ui->TList_Tree->indexBelow(ui->TList_Tree->currentIndex());
if (index.isValid())
    ui->TList_Tree->setCurrentIndex(index);
```

Did a quick check and this appears to do what you want.

Comment: yes this was very helpful thank you. I understand what is happening here. We get index below where we currently are, and if its valid, move to it.